# Python FTPS - how do I set the Type to binary? (I)

Tags: python, ftps

My simple python script connects to an FTPS server, but it sets the type to "A".
I need to set the Type to "I" but I don't see any helper methods to do this.
Here is the code snippet:

```
def connect():
  ftp = FTP_TLS()
  ftp.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
  ftp.debugging = 2
  ftp.connect('foo.com', 20021)
  ftp.login('USER', 'PW')
  ftp.prot_p()
  return ftp

ftp = connect()
print ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

Comment: did you check documentation ? or `help(FTP_TLS)` ? `retrbinary()` ?

Comment: Yes, I did in fact. retrbinary() gets a binary, but it is in the setup of the connection where the type is set to "A" instead of "I". Setting up the connection happens  before any possible file actions, so retrbinary() wouldn't help me much, would it?

Comment: But maybe I'll let it set up as ASCII and just force a binary session. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the solution you are looking for:

The [retrlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) command retrieves lines based on the `encoding` parameter on initialization (referring to a character encoding, which isn't what you are looking for). This automatically sets the type to A. The documentation for `retrlines` mentions the command you are looking for is [retrbinary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) which will create a binary transfer instead.

You said you were worried about setting the type up initially, but if we look at the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ftplib.py#L421), it does exactly what I suggest in the next answer - so really just using `retrbinary` is good enough. The same also occurs for `retrlines` on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ftplib.py#L444) - it just sets the type to A before doing anything.

Not sure if the code was on GitHub when this was posted, but sadly sometimes its easier to parse the code to see the intended behavior if the docs aren't clear.

---

#### Here is a general answer about setting the type with a command:

This is one of the times reading the [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) proved to be the easiest solution. There are several types to choose from + example commands. In this case, we want to use the Image type, or more commonly known as Binary mode:

> Image type is intended for the efficient storage and retrieval of files and for the transfer of binary data.  It is recommended that this type be accepted by all FTP implementations.

```py
def connect():
  ftp = FTP_TLS()
  ftp.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
  ftp.debugging = 2
  ftp.connect('foo.com', 20021)
  ftp.login('USER', 'PW')
  ftp.prot_p()
  ftp.sendcmd('TYPE I')
  return ftp

ftp = connect()
print ftp.retrlines('LIST') # This will always set Type A before executing
print ftp.retrbinary('LIST') # This will always set Type I before executing
```

However, when using ftplib from Python, its usually just easier to use the common methods in ftplib (as they will likely override the type any way, like with `retrbinary`).